# Copy and Pasting SQL Query to MS Word

Tags: sql

Does anyone know if its possible to past SQL queries from phpmyadmin to MS Word and maintain the formatting?

Many thanks

Comment: Why would such not be possible? The only thing is that MS Word probably lacks syntax highlighting. But that does not concern the formatting as such.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy and paste script text from SSMS to Outlook or Word without garbling it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665168/how-to-copy-and-paste-script-text-from-ssms-to-outlook-or-word-without-garbling)

Comment: @MojtabaAhmadi I would guess probably not considering the accepted answer there is 'this is no repro'...